# High contrast video recorder, 1080p, to use with Zoom H6

Tags: video, video-camera

I'm looking for a high contrast video recorder, 1080p. I have ordered a Zoom H6, and I expect to mount it on the camera, and I'd like to be able to syncronize the video and audio.

I'd like to be able to extend its usage with a steadycam, and be able to take regular high-quality pictures with it too.

But my primary expected usage is to record video outdoors in high contrast environments, and secondarily record video of speakers in front of a bright projection screen.

Comment: There really isn't enough detail here to make a meaningful recommendation.  How high contrast do you need?  Is dynamic range your primary motivator?  Are you open to systems that take alternating frames of exposure and do HDR video by post processing?  What is your price range?  What other requirements do you have?  Right now it pretty much just consists of "go on dxomark, sort by DR and pick the best one in your price range".

Comment: @AJHenderson are you saying that DR (dynamic range?) is what I'm looking for?  Would any of those cameras (haven't been to dxomark yet, but that's my next stop) allow me to sync audio with the H6?

Comment: @AJHenderson can't find DR to sort by... oh wait, it's an alias for "landscape"

Comment: Yes, DR is dynamic range.  It's the more common term for what you are looking for (difference between the largest and darkest thing that can be captured) and it is generally measured in EVs.  You aren't going to get anything that supports genlock syncing or the like in a consumer price range, so you just will need to manually sync or use a mic/line input fed from the output of the H6n.  Personally, I just do manual syncing.